# .htaccess file re-write does not work

Tags: .htaccess

I need to re-direct a none existant url to the real url for example:

/timetable needs to point to /real-timetable

I already have a re-direct pointing non www domain to www.domain and that works fine.
I have added a second re-direct but that continues to show a 404 error page for the non-existent url.

In my htaccess file, i have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^timetable(/.*)$ real-timetable$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^timetable(/.*)?$ /real-timetable$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.
And test now with new browser (cache problem).

Comment: i have an even stranger issue now! the url now looks like this: /var/www/vhosts/hostname.ip.secureserver.net/timetable/real-timetable which ends in a 404 page...

Comment: well: http://www.example.com/var/www/vhosts/hostname.ip.secureserver.net/example/real-timetable (where the  /example/ is the domain name)

Comment: I haven't used this before - apologies